# Access global actor property from its shared instance

Tags: swift, concurrency, actor, swift-concurrency

I'm learning about the new concurrency model that Swift offers with its `actor` mechanism and I'm having a hard time figuring out the concrete use of a `globalActor` (except from `@MainActor`).

Given this example:

```
@globalActor
actor TestGlobalActor {
    static var shared = TestGlobalActor()
    
    var data = [1, 2, 3]
}

@TestGlobalActor
class TestClass {
    func handleData() {
        print(TestGlobalActor.shared.data) //  Actor-isolated property 'data' can not be referenced from global actor 'TestGlobalActor'
    }
}
```

1. why cannot I access the `data` property of my global actor given the fact that the method `handleData` is supposed to perform on `TestGlobalActor`
2. Is a global actor supposed to be used in this way, by adding methods and variables in it? or is it just a standalone piece of boilerplate code that is not meant to be extended?

I was able to get the result I expected the above code to produce, but it requiered me to add another inbetween singleton class:

```
@globalActor
actor TestGlobalActor {
    static var shared = TestGlobalActor()
}

@TestGlobalActor
class Singleton {
    static var shared = Singleton()
    private init() {}
    
    var data = [1, 2, 3]
}

@TestGlobalActor
class TestClass {
    func handleDate() {
        print(Singleton.shared.data) // ✅
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference, see [SE-0316](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0316-global-actors.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By annotating something with a global actor, that thing is isolated to the `shared` instance of the global actor. But there could be other instances of the actor!

So just by declaring `shared` as a `var`, the code is not really safe. `shared` could easily be set to some other instance later down the line, and I don't know what will happen after that. Accessing the `var shared` will give you a warning if you use the `-warn-concurrency` option.

Let's make that a `let`:

```
@globalActor
actor TestGlobalActor {
    static let shared = TestGlobalActor()
    
    var data = [1, 2, 3]
}
```

But it is still not safe accessing `data` from `handleData`. Swift isn't smart enough to see that this access of `data` accesses the same instance of `TestGlobalActor` that is used when you use it as a global actor.

In other words, as far as actor isolation is concerned, `TestGlobalActor.shared.data` "looks the same" as `TestGlobalActor().data`. In either case, Swift thinks that the instance on which `data` is accessed is not the same instance as the global actor.

What you can do is mark `data` as `@TestGlobalActor` too:

```
@globalActor
actor TestGlobalActor {
    static let shared = TestGlobalActor()
    
    @TestGlobalActor
    var data = [1, 2, 3]
}
```

This makes your code compile, but it also means that the `data` of other `TestGlobalActor` instances are also isolated to the global actor, and not the individual actor instances, which is quite weird.

Of course, if you intend on only having one instance of `TestGlobalActor`, then there is no problem. Write a `private init() {}` in there while you're at it.

If you do intend on having multiple instances of `TestGlobalActor`, then using a global actor probably isn't suitable. Move `data` somewhere else, or move whatever uses `data` into `TestGlobalActor`.

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was looking for thank you very much.